# To include methods in a model or not?

Tags: php

I have a class which serves as a model for an image:

```
class Image
{
    public $imageId;
    public $title;
    public $description;
    public $filename;
    public $enabled;
    public $galleryId;
    public $galleryName;
    public $orderNum;
}
```

I also have a class, `ImageMapper` which grabs the information about the image from the DB and fills the `Image` object up with the appropriate data. I'm not going to show you `ImageMapper` because it's a really nasty piece of code :-)

Here is an example of how I do that:

```
$image = new Image();
$image->imageId = $previouslyRetrievedId;
$imageMapper = new ImageMapper();
$image = $imageMapper->find($image->imageId);
```

My question is: where should I include methods for converting info about the image. For example, the `$enabled` property of the Image class is represented in the database by a 0 or a 1. When I display that property on a page that is to be read by humans, I would rather it display "No" or "Yes", respectively. Should I include a function to translate the values in the Image class, the ImageMapper class, on the page which displays the Yes or No to the user, or somewhere else?

I have heard that it is bad to include functions in a data object, which is what I am calling the Image object.

Here is an example of the method I am referring to:

```
public function getEnabledAsText()
{
    if(!$this->enabled) {
        return 'No';
    }
    return 'Yes';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably write an `ImageDataPresenter` class and use it to "translate" ugly `Image` properties into pretty human readable text.

```
$presenter=new ImageDataPresenter($imageobj);
echo $presenter->enabled; //'yes'
```

Comment: I agree with that suggestion in principle, but because PHP hasn't got "friend" classes or equivalent, the members of Image all have to be public for ImageDataPresenter to get at them. Therefore in PHP I would be inclined to provide at least setters and getters in the Image class. (I know letseatfood has made them all public, but in general they should not be public without good reason).

Comment: @Colin Fine:  I make all my properties protected (unless I'm sure they won't be extended) and use the `__get()` and `__set()` 'magic' methods to deal with this issue. I didn't mention it because I thought it beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Model should be only for interact with the data source only and return the data source result to the controller.

You should either create function in the controller or it should be created as helper and translate values to display format.

Helper is nothing but helps views to use minimal logics.